# Did i use *meanwhile* and *so* in appropriate way in the following sentence?

Tags: usage

The aim of this writing is to investigate the behavior of price indices  among states . Understanding the behavior of price indices has great importance to policymakers. ***Meanwhile***, CPI is most the commonly used, ***so*** not complete, measure of cost-of-living and therefore the existence of price divergence  would have important messages for the standard of living.

Comment: There's much proofreading to be done here before we can really answer your question. What meaning was implied? What do you mean by saying **not complete**? What is CPI?

Comment: CPI is a price index. It is also a proxy for measuring cost of living but it has some shortcomings for this purpose (not complete proxy). I edited the sentence.

Comment: **Meanwhile** is okay but there a problem with **so not complete** either with the definition or the lack of a verb, **is** for instance - **so is not complete**. However, even that doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: I'd also add **the** before **most commonly used**.

Comment: what about *although not complete*?

Comment: Maybe something like "**Meanwhile, CPI is the most commonly used measure of cost-of-living, thus has some shortcomings and isn't complete, and therefore..."**

Comment: **although** doesn't fit in here in corcodance with **commonly used**

Comment: I want to say why studying the price (CPI) convergence is important. One reason that it is important is that CPI is a proxy for measuring the cost of living. And therefore when it is non-convergence it shows that the cos of living among states is different

Comment: Why did you use the word **complete** in this case? Are you aware of its definitions?

Comment: I mean it is not a perfect proxy for measuring the cost of living.

Comment: **but not the most suitable (perfect, appropriate)**

Comment: "Meanwhile" is a poor choice here. The thought would be more accurately rendered as _"**Currently**, CPI is the most commonly used, **yet** incomplete, measure of..."_ (Note that you have reversed the correct order of the words in the phrase "the most".)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need *Meanwhile*, since there is no time comparison. So how about:

> **While not perfect**, (the) CPI is *the* most commonly used measure of cost-of-living, and therefore the existing <del>of</del> price divergence among provinces would have important implications for standard of living.

Optionally, you could also use:

> the existence of price divergence

Comment: Also "for *their* standard of living".